# RSS feed in CommonSpot

Tags: coldfusion, rss, commonspot

I'm new to CommonSpot, now I need to write some code for a RSS feed in CommonSpot. How can I  create a flexible RSS feed, as the user should be able to create a link then tag it to be syndicated via RSS.

I'm not sure whether this is the right question for my problem.

Like one in this http://water.epa.gov/commonspot/help/content/contributors_reference/create_rss_feed.htm

Answer (score 0):

I doubt there is an easy answer to this but I would grab Ray's RSS.cfc off of www.riaforge.org as a starting point. It takes a query as an argument and returns an RSS feed formatted correctly for the version you specify. I would wager the rest would be custom programming.

Comment: Also note - there is an RSS generator native to CF As of CF9. Check out the docs for cffeed.

Comment: actually i dint get that..!! I dont know how to link all those.. I'm very new to commonspot as well as coldfusion. I dont know where to keep those files etc etc things... I need the rss feed of some other sites in one element of my webpage. Can u help me on this??

Comment: Vamshi... the docs for Coldfusion are online. You will need to read them if for no other reason than to keep folks from this forum from poking fun at you :)  Don't worry - the docs will have what you need.